# Creating grid with one big square using auto layout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

Please advise on how should I approach implementing the following layout using Xcode's Auto Layout?

The idea here is that `redView` and all `blueViews` are all perfect squares with equal spacing.

I was only able to create working version with the `redView` and 2 vertical `blueView` without the bottom 3 `blueViews`.

[image: auto layout grid issue]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

---

Here is how I would approach it.

1. First create the big yellow square.  Give it an aspect ratio of `1:1`.  Add a constraint to center it horizontally in the view.  Give it leading edge and top edge constraints.
2. Add view `B`.  Give it an aspect ratio of `1:1`. Align it with the top edge and trailing edge of the yellow square.
3. Add view `C`.  Align it to the trailing edge of yellow and center it vertically in yellow.  Add equal width and equal constraints to view `B`.  Give it a vertical space of `16` from view `B`.
4. Add view `F`.  Align it to the trailing edge and bottom edge of yellow.  Give it equal width and height of view `C`.
5. Add view `E`.  Align it to the bottom edge of yellow.  Center it horizontally in yellow.  Give it equal width and height to `F`.
6. Add view `D`.  Align it to the leading edge and bottom edge of yellow.  Give it equal width and height to `E`.
7. Add view `A`.  Give it aspect `1:1`.  Align it to leading edge of yellow and top edge of yellow.  Align its bottom edge with bottom edge of `C`.
8. Change background color of yellow to `clear`.

That will do it.  The yellow square will resize for all devices, and the red and blue squares will be sized accordingly. You can change the distance constraint between views `B` and `C` and all gaps will adjust automatically, which makes this easy to adjust for the desired look.

---

Here is an example running in the simulator.  I hooked up the slider to change the value of the `constant` for the constraint setting the distance between views `B` and `C`.

[image]

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because it answers the original question, and makes it very easy to adjust the spacing :)

Comment: Thank you very much vacawama and DonMag. I managed to do it using your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

See if this makes sense...

[image]

Embed all views in a "containing" view (it's yellow here, but the background color would be set to clear). This is the view that will control the overall size of your "grid."

Set the yellow width and height each to 320. As a starting point, this allows nice, even numbers: the Red view is 210x210 and the Blue views are each 100x100, with a 10pt gap between the views.

- Put the Red view at x:0 y:0 - upper-left corner
- Put Blue 1 at x:220 y:0 - upper-right corner
- Put Blue 2 at x:220 y:110
- Put Blue 3 at x:220 y:220
- Put Blue 4 at x:110 y:220
- And finally Blue 5 at x:0 y:220

The key to keeping the grid layout when the Yellow "containing view" changes size is to use a combination of Proportional Widths, Aspect Ratios and relative-to positions and sizes.

- Red gets Top and Leading constraints of 0 to its superview (Yellow) - keeps it top-left-corner, an Aspect Ratio of 1:1 (keeps it square), and a Proportional Width to its superview (Yellow) of 210:320. That means if you change the Yellow view from 320x320 to 160x160, for example, the Red view will be constrained to 105x105.
- Blue 1 gets Top and Trailing constraints of 0 to its superview (Yellow) - keeps it top-right-corner, an Aspect Ratio of 1:1 (keeps it square), and a Proportional Width to its superview (Yellow) of 100:320. That means if you change the Yellow view from 320x320 to 160x160, for example, Blue 1 will be constrained to 50x50.

That's it for the "tricky" constraints!

- For Blue 2 thru 5, set each one to Equal Width and Equal Height to Blue 1.
- Blue 2 gets Trailing of 0 to its superview (right-edge of Yellow), and Bottom equal-to Bottom of Red.
- Blue 3 gets Trailing and Bottom of 0 to its superview (Yellow) - keeps it bottom-right-corner.
- Blue 4 gets Bottom of Bottom of 0 to its superview (Yellow), and Trailing equal-to Trailing of Red.
- Blue 5 gets Leading and Bottom of 0 to its superview (Yellow) - keeps it bottom-left-corner.

The Yellow containing view should have a 1:1 ratio to keep it square, then normal Position and Width constraints.

You can see the actual storyboard here: https://github.com/DonMag/ScratchPad (the Grid Of Boxes example)

Comment: I up voted your answer since I think it is a good approach to maintaining the same look on all devices.